# Space and new line as character

Tags: r

I need to substitute the following string [space newline space] with [quotationmark newline quotation mark]. I'm using stri_replace_all_regex from the library stringi, but the following code seems to be wrong:

```
 stri_replace_all_regex(tx, pattern='\\s\n\\s', replacement='"\n"')
```

What am I mistaking?

Comment: Put string example .

Answer (score 0):

Add another slash

```r
library(stringr)

"sample \n text, text \n sampled" %>% 
  str_replace_all(pattern = "\\s\\\n\\s", replacement = "?\n?")

#> [1] "sample?\n?text, text?\n?sampled"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>